# Are lncrna and ncrna worthwhile tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

A user has just made the tags [ncrna](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ncrna) and [lncrna](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lncrna) for non-coding RNA and long-non-coding RNA respectively. Are these tags worth having? The abbreviations are obscure and not likely to be tried/used by users posting relevant questions. Also there is already a [noncoding-rna](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noncoding-rna) and I think this would suffice for both [ncrna](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ncrna) and [lncrna](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lncrna).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless we get significantly more questions about the various kinds of non-coding RNA, I don't think we need more than the [noncoding-rna](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noncoding-rna) tag for now.

The abbreviations also don't work well as tags because they become all lowercase, and ncrna is harder to read than ncRNA.

Comment: agreed that they are hard to read